# Yangians as unique deformation

Tags: lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

In Drinfeld's paper "Hopf algebras and the quantum Yang-Baxter equation" there is a statement (Theorem 2) that Yangian is a unique quantization of the corresponding Lie bialgebra.

My question is whether someone is aware of the place where the proof of this statement is written.

Comment: There is theorem 12.1.1 in Chari and Pressley's "A Guide to Quantum Groups"

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: Yes, but there is no proof there either, only a suggestion why this is a "natural" quantization.